# Call function from class in c# using jquery ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, webmethod

I have been able to call the function using ajax using following code

```
function AjaxCall() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Default.aspx/Server_HelloWorld',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (result) { alert(result.d); }
    })

}

using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
```

aspx.cs Ajax Webmethod,

```
[WebMethod]
public String Server_HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello, How are you?";
}
```

But if i don't have any `.aspx` page,  i have only .html page with a class say `myfunclass.cs`. How do i call the same function from here. I have tried but fail

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: 'myfunclass.cs/Server_HelloWorld',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (result) { alert(result.d); }
    })
```

Comment: This does not work. You can't call any method in your `.cs`. It must be a MVC Controller or a HTTP Handler (MVC Controller is in fact a HTPP Handler..)

Answer (score 0):

You cant just call *.cs file. You need to create some backend, like ASP.NET MVC Web API like in example [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)